# How To Get Specifie Product in Laravel Array

Tags: php, laravel

im trying to get those products that have css and html technology.note that (html and css) are not the only parameters that can be used.sometimes could be more, for example ['java','html,'python',...] and so on

in this result i have 2 product but it should be 1,the one with (id:1) becuz only this product have both (html and css)technology

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "First Product",
    "prte": [
      {
        "product_id": 1,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "technology": {
          "id": 1,
          "title_en": "HTML"
        }
      },
      {
        "product_id": 1,
        "technology_id": 2,
        "technology": {
          "id": 2,
          "title_en": "CSS"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Second Product",
    "prte": [
      {
        "product_id": 2,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "technology": {
          "id": 1,
          "title_en": "HTML"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and this one is the Controller

```
$products = Product::with(['prte' => function ($query){

    $query->with(['technology' => function ($query){
        $query->whereIn('title_en',['HTML','CSS']);
    }]);
 

}])->get();


return view('find',compact('products'));
```

hope u guys could help me

Comment: What exactly error are your getting? Can explain what you wanna achieve and what issues you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Try where instead of whereIn.

```
$products = Product::with(['prte' => function ($query){

     $query->with(['technology' => function ($query){
         $query->where('title_en','HTML')->where('title_en','CSS');
     }]); 

 }])->get();

 return view('find',compact('products'));
```

Comment: still not working. this is the result i got   
 http://s13.picofile.com/file/8401152192/screencapture_127_0_0_1_8000_find_2020_06_26_10_31_43.png

Comment: What is the relationships between your model?